# Checking 2 tables for identical IDs and returning 1/0 in column if ID in table 1 exists in table 2

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables, 1 containing all reservation ids, and 1 containing reservation ids for livestream reservations. I am trying to write a query that checks to see if a reservation id exists in the livestream table, and returns '1' if true & '0' if false. I figure the best way to do this is with a case statement that returns my result if the reservation id exists in the livestream table, but I am running into issues. Is there a better way to do this?

```
with table_name as(

select
    reservation_id
from all_reservations 
)

select t.*,
    case when exists(l.reservation_id)
    then '1'
    else '0' end as is_livestream
from livestream_reservations l
left join table name t
    on l.reservation_id = t.reservation_id
```

Comment: Would it not be less error prone to either make ```livestream_reservations``` a child table of ```all_reservations``` via a ```FOREIGN KEY``` or have a trigger on ```livestream_reservations```  that creates a row in ```all_reservations```  so you know there is a connection?

Comment: Yes, but I don't have permissions to create/modify tables in this DB unfortunately

Comment: Aah, that would be a problem:)

Comment: `isnull()` would have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as `reservation_id` shows up with at most one record in `livestream_reservations`, this will work for you:

```
select r.*,
       case
         when l.reservation_id is null then 0
         else 1
       end as is_livestream
  from reservations r
       left join livestream_reservations l
              on l.reservation_id = r.reservation_id;
```

The `case` relies on the fact that a failure to join to `livestream_reservations` returns `null` in all columns from that table.

In case there may be more than one row with the same `reservation_id` in the `livestream_reservations` table, then you could do this:

```
with ls_count as (
  select reservation_id, count(*) as count_livestream
    from livestream_reservations
   group by reservation_id
)
select r.*, coalesce(lc.count_livestream, 0) as count_livestream
  from reservations r
       left join ls_count lc on lc.reservation_id = r.reservation_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `exists` and using booleans:

```
select r.*,
       (exists (select 1 from livestream_reservations lr where lr.reservation_id = r. reservation_id)
       ) as is_livestream
from reservations r;
```

There is a good chance that this is faster than other solutions.  More importantly, it avoids problems with duplicates in `livestream_reservations`.

Comment: @SteveDooley . . . I answered because not only is this shorter but it avoids problems with duplicates.